# Getting RemoteFX USB redirection functioning for an iPod

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remotefx

I'm currently traveling, and have only a laptop, iPod, and phone with me. I would like to sync my iPod with my desktop computer at home, which appears to, in principle, be possible. I am already able to use Remote Desktop to access said desktop for other purposes, however I have not been able to get RemoteFX to function in order to sync the iPod.

Specifically, in the RDP "Local Resources and Devices" dialog on the client machine, the option for "Other supported RemoteFX devices" simply fails to appear under any circumstances (even when running the client as administrator).

- The client machine is running Windows 10 Home x64, fully updated as of 4/5/18. I have managed to install `gpedit` on this machine, despite it not coming with Home Edition.
- The host machine is running Windows 10 Pro x64, likewise fully updated.

I have made the following Group Policy changes on both the host and client under `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services`, to no avail:

- `Remote Desktop Connection Client\RemoteFX USB Device Redirection\Allow RDP redirection of other supported RemoteFX USB devices` - Enabled
- `Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection\Do not allow supported Plug and Play device redirection` - Disabled
- `Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment\Enable RemoteFX encoding for RemoteFX clients designed for Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1` - Enabled
- `Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment\RemoteFX for Windows Server 2008 R2\Configure RemoteFX` - Enabled

I am confident these Group Policy settings are indeed being applied. (I have restarted many times as well as run `gpupdate /force`.)

I have also made these changes on the client:

- Disabled a driver `Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)` that seems to be known to cause problems with RemoteFX.
- Added the iPod's interface class GUID `{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}` under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\Client\UsbSelectDeviceByInterfaces` in the registry.

There exists a `Remote Desktop Device Redirector Bus` under `System devices` on the client's Device Manager.
There are also a number of devices listed under `Universal Serial Bus controllers`, however none of these devices' associated drivers include `tsusbflt.sys`. **I highly suspect this is the problem, but have no idea how to solve it.** The driver does indeed exist on the system, and I can even manually start it, though doing so has no effect on the problem.

How can I enable this driver for the computer's USB hub, or is there something else I should try?